# Determining a basis for the subspace of T(2,2) consisting of transformations such that T(v) = 0 for a specific vector v

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Question: Find a basis for the subspace $S$:

$S$ is the subspace of $T(2,2)$ consisting of linear transformations $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $T(\mathbf{v}) =\mathbf{0}$ for a specific vector $\mathbf{v}$.

I can't figure out how to approach this question. Here's what I have so far:

Let $T(\mathbf{v}) = A\mathbf{v}$ where

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{pmatrix}, \,\,\, \mathbf{v} = \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Then

$$ a_{11} \cdot v_1 + a_{12} \cdot v_2 = 0, \\
 a_{21} \cdot v_1 + a_{22} \cdot v_2 = 0. $$

Let $a_{11} = a_{21} = v_2, a_{12} = a_{22} = -v_1$.

Then a basis for S is

$$ \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} v_2 &   -v_1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ v_2  & -v_1 \end{pmatrix} \right\} $$

which is linearly independent and spans $S$. However, it doesn't seem like a usual basis... any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is perfectly correct. Note only that if $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$ then the "basis" you wrote is not a basis - it is not linearly independent nor it spans $S$. If $\mathbf{v} = 0$ then $S = T(2,2)$.

Comment: It is okay to have a basis without only numbers (or expressions like the basis for **P^n**? (Yes, if **v** = **0** then the basis would be the same as the basis for **R^2x2**, correct?)

Comment: Yes - if the vector $\mathbf{v}$ is not given to you explicitly, the best you can get is to express the basis for $S$ in terms of the coordinates of $\mathbf{v}$ (which are not known) like you did.

Comment: Hmm... okay. I can't figure out what happens when v1 = 0 and v2 =/= 0, or vice versa, though.

Comment: You still obtain a basis. Try this with $\mathbf{v} = (0,1)$.

Comment: Would a basis then be {[1  0; 0  0], [0 0; 1 0]}?

Comment: Is it appropriate to express this basis (for a subspace defined by linear transformations) as a set of matrices?